# filebeat is not creating index with my name

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am using filebeat to send my application logs to Elasticsearch and directly connecting to my Elasticsearch for sending the logs.

**My file beat configuration**

```
filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
    paths:
      - "/var/log/*.log"
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.overwrite: true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["aws-es:443"]
  output.elasticsearch.index: "myapp-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}
```

Please note that in `output.elasticsearch.index:` I am giving myapp as prefix to my index name in Elasticsearch but filebeat is creating index with `filebeat-7.7.0-2020.05.31` name ie using its own name `filebeat` as prefix which I don't want as I am having multiple applications and want to create a separate index for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property name is wrong. It is `output.elasticsearch.output.elasticsearch.index`, but should be only `output.elasticsearch.index`
Change your config to

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["aws-es:443"]
  index: "myapp-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}
```

Comment: yeah now got `Exiting: setup.template.name and setup.template.pattern have to be set if index name is modified`

Comment: Also, need to set in `false` the property: `setup.ilm.enabled`, __ILM:  _Index Lyfecycle Management___. More on this here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.9/ilm.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `setup.template.name`
and `setup.template.pattern`
as mentioned in the error message. Please add below extra lines in your filebeat.yml.

```
setup.template:
  name: 'myapp'
  pattern: 'myapp-*'
  enabled: false
```

Now your complete `filebeat.yml`
should look like

filebeat.config:
modules:
path: $ {
path.config
}
/modules.d/ * .yml
reload.enabled: false

```
  filebeat.inputs:
    -type: log
  paths:
    -"/var/log/*.log"
  setup.ilm.enabled: false
  setup.template.overwrite: true
  output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: ["aws-es:443"]
  output.elasticsearch.index: "myapp-%{[agent.version]}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}

  setup.template:
    name: 'myapp'
    pattern: 'myapp-*'
    enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Filebeat is using `Index Lifecycle Management` by default which is probably good. To change the name of the index and index template with ILM turned on you can do this:

```
setup.ilm.policy_name: yourname
setup.ilm.rollover_alias: yourname-%{[agent.version]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following property to your config, it should work as expected.

```
setup.ilm.enabled: false
```

Comment: the line is already there in the OP code